ssh-connection from outside (and inside) fails -- Linux Mint
PROBLEM

no ssh connection to my local computer possible, even not ssh [myname]:127.0.0.1

ssh localhost, on the other hand, works

entering sshd: ALL and ssh: ALL in /etc/hosts.allow does not help

turning off the router's firewall does not help either


Your help would be appreciated!
DETAILS
**sudo ss -tulpn | grep :22** yields

tcp     LISTEN   0        128              0.0.0.0:22             0.0.0.0:*      users:(("sshd",pid=1075,fd=4))                                                 
tcp     LISTEN   0        128                 [::]:22                [::]:*      users:(("sshd",pid=1075,fd=3))

**ssh -X -vvv [myname]@[my-ip-address]**  [typical login attempt from somewhere outside, various places & networks]

OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.7, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /users/[myname]/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 3: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname [my_ip_address] is address
debug1: hostname canonicalisation enabled, will re-parse configuration
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /users/[myname]/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 3: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/users/[myname]/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/users/[myname]/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to [my-ip-address] [[my-ip-address]] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 4 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: connect to address [my-ip-address] port 22: Connection timed out

**netstat -tnlp**  (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -    

**ps -ef | grep sshd**

root        1075       1  0 12:48 ?        00:00:00 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
[myname]        21645   16166  0 14:50 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sshd

**Firewall:** none on my machine, turning off the router's firewall does not change anything

On my computer sshd (root) and ssh-client ([myname]) are running

**telnet [my-ip-address] 22** is taciturn and quits after some time

**ping** to my machine works fine 


Additional info: when entering "ssh localhost", the file /var/log/auth.log acknowledges "pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: ...", while logging in with "ssh [user]@127.0.0.1" this leaves no trace in the auth.log file.

Welcome to SuperUser. Please add any additional information, such as what you have added down here as a comment, to the question itself using the EDIT button. Making your question more clear and complete is the best way to get good answers, and so we strongly encourage regular use of the EDIT button to do that.
